# Dropdown with :remote=>true links not rendering ajax partial in Rails 3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rendering

After looking around for an answer to my problem for some time I have now come to the conclusion that I need to ask my first ever question on SO. I hope you can help!

As you can see below I have a list with links that via ajax renders different partials when clicked. Everything here worked fine, until I decided to change the list to a dropdown-list with javascript (with some help from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/).

All the functionality in the dropdown works except the "link_to :remote => true"-part. Nothing at all happens when the links in the dropdown are clicked. I know that the main problem is in the dropdown.js code, but as I'm fairly new to programming I simply cannot find a solution.

**Question?**

> So basically, how do I make the links in my dropdown render my
>   partials with ajax?

**Views/products/Index.html.erb**

```
<div id="proftab" class="wrapper-dropdown">
 <span>Popular</span>
 <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><%= link_to "Popular", products_index_path(:feed => "popular"), :remote => true%></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Following", products_index_path(:feed => "following"), :remote => true%></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Sales", products_index_path(:feed => "sales"), :remote => true%></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Expensive", products_index_path(:feed => "expensive"), :remote => true%></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Trendspotter", products_index_path(:feed => "trendspotter"), :remote => true%></li>
 </ul></div> 

<div class="row">
<div id="profile">
    <!-- The rendering is going on here -->
</div>
```

**Controllers/products_controller.erb**

```
def index
 case params[:feed]
  when "sales"
    @products = #Different scopes
  when "expensive"
    @products = #Different scopes
  when "trendspotter"
    @products
  when "following"
    @products = #Different scopes
  else
    @products = #Different scopes
  end
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js
  end
end
```

**Views/products/index.js.erb**

```
<% if params[:feed] == 'sales' %>
   $("#profile").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'sales')) %>");
<% elsif params[:feed] == 'following' %>
   $("#profile").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'following')) %>");
<% elsif params[:feed] == 'expensive' %>
   $("#profile").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'expensive')) %>");
<% else %> 
   $("#profile").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'popular')) %>");
 <% end %>
```

**Routes.rb**

```
  root :to => 'products#index', :constraints => lambda{|req| !req.session[:user_id].blank?}
  root :to => 'pages#home'
```

**Assets/javascript/dropdown.js AKA the problem**

```
function DropDown(el) {
this.proftab = el;
this.placeholder = this.proftab.children('span');
this.opts = this.proftab.find('ul.dropdown > li');
this.val = '';
this.index = -1;
this.initEvents();
}


DropDown.prototype = {
initEvents : function() {
    var obj = this;

    obj.proftab.on('click', function(event){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        return false;
    });

    obj.opts.on('click',function(){
        var opt = $(this);
        obj.val = opt.text();
        obj.index = opt.index();
        obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
    });
},
getValue : function() {
    return this.val;
},
getIndex : function() {
    return this.index;
}
}



$(function() {
var proftab = new DropDown( $('#proftab') );
$(document).click(function() {
     // all dropdowns
    $('.wrapper-dropdown').removeClass('active');
 });

});
```